# How can I get my indoor Lemon tree with no leaves or branches to grow a new branch or leaf?

Tags: trees, pruning, lemons, branches

I have this lemon tree (Meyer I think) and since April it has not had any leaves. It did go through a period without water (and it was indoors, but I put it in front of the window). I have pruned all the dead branches off, and when I scratch the trunk there’s still green underneath, however it’s been a while and nothing has changed. Ever since that event in April, I have been regularly watering (when the soil gets dry), and in June I moved back home from university where I was able to put the lemon tree in the sun in the garden (alongside regularly watering). I am a bit panicked because I have no clue how to get the tree to grow a branch or leaf.

[image: Dead Meyer Lemon Tree in a pot]

A few questions, should I leave it in direct sun or indirect sunlight since it has no leaves? Should I cut the branch closer to the branch collar to encourage new branch growth? And should I avoid using fertilizer, I also saw someone here say they would water their branches and spray them is that something I should do? Any help at all is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are scratching the stem, **if it is still green**, then you should continue your routine work.

I don't have any experience with any lemon tree, but I do have such an experience with thinner yet woody plant(stem). It did grow new leaves after 4-5 months, so hope for the best.

Routine:

1. Keep it under shade, bright spot, but NO DIRECT SUNLIGHT.
2. Water throughly until extra water drains out from the bottom.
3. After this, don't water the pot unless the soil dries, else root rot will start.
4. When the soil dries, repeat step 2. Continue 2>3>4.
5. You can spray water on the branches, but keep checking for fungus attack(I didn't do this step at all).
6. Do not use any kind of fertiliser now, the plant won't be able to handle them.
7. Even if new leaves come out, don't immediately put the plant under sun.

All  the best !!

Comment: Thank you! That gives me hope that my tree might be able to be what it once was.

Answer (score 0):

Citrus trees need full sun outdoors to grow leaves and to be pollinated by bees so they they grow fruit. Lots of water in summer and the best fertilizer is palm food